# SAP JCo3 table empty although connected

Tags: java, sapjco3

Hi I am using SAP JCo3 connector along with .dll file provided with the jar.
the destination is successfully connected. My problem is that when I am doing the `function.execute(destination)` the `function.getTableParameterList().getTable("PART_LIST")` returns an empty table with zero rows.

My code to achieve the connectivity is as below:

```
JCoDestination dest  = JCoDestinationManager.getDestination("EOMP");
dest.ping();
JCoRepository repo=  dest.getRepository();
JCoFunctionTemplate ftemplate = repo.getFunctionTemplate("Z_BAPI_GET_ESO_PART");
JCoFunction function = ftemplate.getFunction();
JCoParameterList importParams = function.getImportParameterList();
        
importParams.setValue("ESO","R1S00444");
importParams.toXML();
        
function.execute(dest);
       
JCoParameterList tableParamList=function.getTableParameterList();
JCoTable table=tableParamList.getTable("PART_LIST");
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same phenomenon a few days back ...

After a while, I noticed that the parameter to be passed - if it is a char - must be as long as the size of the field.

Your field length is 12 and is char.
If you call your function directly in SAP, you pass on e.g. `1234567891` and get your desired result.

However, if you call it from the RFC connection, you must prepare the record `001234567891`.

Look up the DB-table. Try it with the given example in the table.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to debug your ABAP code.
If it would fill in some rows to this PART_LIST table you would also get them at Java side.
There is no obvious error in your Java code, except `importParams.toXML()` is superfluous and also `dest.ping()` is not needed.